# Video File (.MOV) Opens in VLC and Other Players But Not in Premiere

Tags: premiere, video-editor

A four Gig .MOV video file plays perfectly on VLC, Windows Media Player and PotPlayer but when imported into Adobe Premiere Pro 5.5 the following error message appears :

"The file has no audio or video streams".

I've tried four different video file converter / repair tools (including Remo, Stellar Phoenix and StreamClip). All three tools actually worsened the problem instead of fixing it. Most of them made the file unplayable (as well as not editable). As a precaution, I only tried the repair tools on a backup of the file so as not to ruin the original.

I've searched but cannot find an example of a video file that plays back perfectly but cannot be imported into Premiere.

Comment: Share what [mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) says for the file. Use View->Text mode.

Comment: I installed MediaInfo and exported the analysis here : http://www.hexgrids.com/MediaInfo.html.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue. I found 2 different solutions for my file.

The issue has to do with some kind of codec issue with newer versions of Adobe that no longer support certain .mov encoding types (or something like that)

**Solution 1: Rename the file extension to .mp4**

Believe it or not, this is actually working for some people. Read toward the end of [this thread](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2488825).

I tried it myself and was finally able to open the file in Adobe CS5. However, only the audio appeared in the timeline. No video.

**Solution 2: Re-encode using VLC**

There's a fix in [this thread](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2473026) from Sasha L. (dated April 11, 2018) that involves re-encoding the file using VLC. I tried this and it worked. The steps once opening VLC are:

1. Click "Media" in the menu bar
2. Select "Convert/Save"
3. Choose your source file
4. Select your destination file type (click the toggle icon in order to access more advanced encoding settings)
5. Choose your destination file name
6. Export

When I used this method I was able to export a visual-only video (no audio).

Between the 2 methods I was able to export audio and visual and import them into Adobe Premiere so that they could be combined.

Best of luck!

Comment: +1 for re-encoding, I found that .MOV files from my newer iPhone wouldn't import into an older version or Premiere. I re-encoded to MP4 using Handbrake (have never tried VLC for this), and the file came in fine. OP, also be careful it isn't anything to do with a 4GB file limit, most newer software avoids those issues, but if your software is old enough, that might be problematic.